# Leap Motion - CircleGesture is not defined?

Tags: python, leap-motion

Could someone please tell me why am I getting the following error?

> > NameError: global name 'CircleGesture' is not defined

in my function `on_connect` I am setting the Circle gesture:

```
controller.enable_gesture(Leap.Gesture.TYPE_CIRCLE);
```

but whenever I try to do anything for example:

```
for gesture in frame.gestures():
    circle = CircleGesture(gesture);
```

I'm in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the module, and without seeing your code this is just a guess, but from your question I infer that you use [this Leap Motion API](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Python/API/index.html), and did something like `import Leap` in your code.

This way, you do not yet have the `CircleGesture` class in your name space, but you have to access it [from within the `Leap` module](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), just like you did with `Leap.Gesture.TYPE_CIRCLE`.

Try this: `circle = Leap.CircleGesture(gesture)`

(as a side note: in Python, you do not have to terminate your lines with `;`)

Comment: @user1326876 Just browsing through some of my older answers. Did this work?